# Ajax search doesn't work the second time (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem changing items after searching.

I looked at similar threads but found no solution there :(

It looks like the first time the page loads well - the first time the entire Index.cshtml page is loaded which contains a collection of books in the selected category.

There is a search engine on the page - after searching for "manual" - ajax correctly replaces elements with those containing "manual" in the name.

Then when I enter something into the search engine a second time (for example "exercises") - the content of the page does not change any more.

I tried to debug and I see that new items are correctly downloaded from the database - the condition "if (Request.IsAjaxRequest ())" is true and the items are passed to partial view - there the "foreach" loop goes through them. Unfortunately, after _Partial, nothing happens.

I can't find a mistake - the strangest thing is that the first ajax call works fine - only the second (and subsequent) bad.

CatalogController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(string categoryName = null, string searchQuery = null)
        {
            if (categoryName == null)
                categoryName = (db.Categories.Find(1)).Name;

            var category = db.Categories.Include("Books").Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == categoryName).Single();

            var books = category.Books.Where(x => (searchQuery == null || x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()) || x.SubTitle.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()) || x.Level.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower())) && !x.Inaccessible);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("_PartialBooksList", books);
            else
                return View(books);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<form class="o-search-form" id="search-form" method="get" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-target="#booksList">
   <input class="o-search-input" id="search-filter" type="search" name="searchQuery" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("SearchTips")" placeholder="Search" />
   <input class="o-search-submit" type="submit" value="" />
</form> 

<div class="row" id="booksList">
   @Html.Partial("_PartialBooksList")
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var setupAutoComplete = function () {
                var $input = $(this);
                var options =
                {
                    source: $input.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), 
                    select: function (event, ui) { 
                        $input = $(this);
                        $input.val(ui.item.label);
                        var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
                        $form.submit();
                    }
                };
                $input.autocomplete(options);  
            };
            var ajaxSubmit = function () { 
                var $form = $(this);
                var settings = {                                            
                    data: $(this).serialize(), 
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),  
                    type: $(this).attr("method")                       
                };
                $.ajax(settings).done(function (result) {    
                    var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
                    var $newContent = $(result);
                    $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);  
                    $newContent.effect("slide");
                });
                return false;
            };
            $("#search-filter").each(setupAutoComplete);
            $("#search-form").submit(ajaxSubmit); 
        });
    </script>
}
```

_PartialBooksList

```
@model IEnumerable<ImpressDev.Models.Book>
@using ImpressDev.Infrastructure
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var book in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-4">
            <a class="o-shop-link" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Catalog", new { bookId = book.BookId })">
                <div class="o-shop-item">
                    <img class="o-shop-img" src="@Url.BookPhotoSourcePath(book.PhotoSource)" />
                    <div class="o-shop-text">
                        <h2>@book.Title</h2>
                        <h6>@book.SubTitle - @book.Level - <b>@book.Price zł.</b></h6>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { bookId = book.BookId })" class="o-shop-button">+ Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the code step by step and found a solution to my problem.

In the first search, replace id="booksList"

```
                    <div class="row" id="booksList">
                            @Html.Partial("_PartialBooksList")
                    </div>
```

partial view in which there was only  without id = booksLists.

In the next search there was no ID in this place and there was nothing to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the case, but try to change this code:

```
$($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
```

To this:

```
$($targetElement).html($newContent);
```

I think the problem is the div element with id="booksList" is replaced after first search. So you don't have this element in the second search.